# Blueprism resource pc gets killed automatically during Java Automation

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

I have a automation done in blue prism whice is scheduled to run every 15 minutes. With lighter loads it completes within about 10 minutes. But depending on the work load sometimes a single run might take few hours. The issue is, when such a long run is encountered, the resource pc gets itself killed during the automation after few hours. It doesn't even wait for the completion of that run.

How can I stop the resource pc shutdown? Is there a maximum time limit in blue prism where it expects a single run should last and if not completed it kills the resource pc? If so how can I increase it?

**Edit:**
After analyzing bit more I found out that the Blue Prism resource PC crashes during my automation run. Seems like a problem between Blue Prism and Java access bridge. Following are the exception details from Windows event log. Is there a way to prevent this crash and continue to run my automation?

> Application: Automate.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description:
>   The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception
>   Info: System.AccessViolationException    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.JAB.WAB32.getAccessibleContextFromHWND(Int32,
>   Int32 ByRef, Int64 ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.JAB.WAB.getAccessibleContextFromHWND(Int32,
>   Int32 ByRef, Int64 ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.JAB.JABWrapper.GetContextFromWindow(Int32)
>   at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsUIModel.GetJABObjects(BluePrism.ApplicationManager.ApplicationManagerUtilities.clsQuery,
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.JAB.JABWrapper, Int32)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsUIModel.GetJABObject(BluePrism.ApplicationManager.ApplicationManagerUtilities.clsQuery,
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.JAB.JABWrapper)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsLocalTargetApp.ProcessCommand_JABCheckExists(BluePrism.ApplicationManager.ApplicationManagerUtilities.clsQuery)
>
> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Object[])    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder,
>   System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsLocalTargetApp.ExecuteQuery(BluePrism.ApplicationManager.ApplicationManagerUtilities.clsQuery)
>   at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsLocalTargetApp.ProcessCommand_Wait(BluePrism.ApplicationManager.ApplicationManagerUtilities.clsQuery)
>
> Exception Info: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException    at
>   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object,
>   System.Object[], System.Object[])    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object,
>   System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder,
>   System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsLocalTargetApp.ExecuteQuery(BluePrism.ApplicationManager.ApplicationManagerUtilities.clsQuery)
>   at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsLocalTargetApp.ProcessQuery(System.String,
>   System.TimeSpan)    at
>   BluePrism.ApplicationManager.clsLocalTargetApp.ProcessQuery(System.String)
>   at
>   BluePrism.AMI.clsAMI.DoWait(System.Collections.Generic.List`1,
>   Int32, clsAMIMessage ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.Stages.clsWaitStartStage.Execute(System.Guid
>   ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcess.RunStep(BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcessBreakpointInfo
>   ByRef, Boolean)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcess.RunAction(RunActions,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcessBreakpointInfo ByRef, Boolean)
>   at BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsVBO.DoDoAction(System.String,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcessStage,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsArgumentList,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsArgumentList ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsBusinessObject.DoAction(System.String,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcessStage,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsArgumentList,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsArgumentList ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.Stages.clsActionStage.Execute(System.Guid
>   ByRef)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcess.RunStep(BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcessBreakpointInfo
>   ByRef, Boolean)    at
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcess.RunAction(RunActions,
>   BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcessBreakpointInfo ByRef, Boolean)
>   at BluePrism.AutomateProcessCore.clsProcess.RunAction(RunActions)
>   at BluePrism.AutomateAppCore.RunnerRecord.RunnerMethod()    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 0):

The resource PC would likely crash when it encounters an unhandled exception. Have a Recover & Resume block in your master process and on Resume, log an error message with the exception details and continue on with the next run.

While this will prevent the crash, you will still have to analyse your java app and the BP java access bridge to identify the root cause. You may want to reach out the BP Support team if you are unable to.